# Merging code chunks in knitr output

Tags: knitr, pandoc

I sometimes find myself in a situation where I end up with two or more adjacent code chunks in an Rmarkdown document. Typically this happens when the code in these chunks forms a logical unit but I want to process them differently in some way. For example, a sequence of commands may contain a function call that takes particularly long to run and I want to cache it separately to avoid re-computing results as much as possible. This leads to separate code blocks in the output directly following each other.

My question is whether it is possible to automatically merge these adjacent chunks into a single output block. I can't find a knitr option to do this but a knitr hook or pandoc filter may be able to do this. Any advice on a good approach to solve this issue is appreciated.